# Hiding email address from bots on PHP contact form

Tags: php, forms, email

I've got a PHP contact form that includes the email address where the form gets emailed to hardcoded as shown below.

Is that sufficiently safe to use or am I likely to get spammed from bots?

What's a reasonable solution?  Would something like this be better?

```
$toemail1 = "email";
$toemail = $toemail1 + "@address.com";
```

original php code:

```
    //name can contain only alpha characters and space
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/",$name))
    {
        $error = true;
        $name_error = "Please enter valid name";
    }
    if(!filter_var($fromemail,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
    {
        $error = true;
        $fromemail_error = "Please enter valid email address";
    }
    if(empty($message))
    {
        $error = true;
        $message_error = "Please enter your message";
    }
    if (!$error)
    {
        //send mail
        $toemail = "email@address.com";
        $subject = "Enquiry from Visitor " . $name;
        $body = "Here goes your Message Details: \n\n Name: $name \n From: $fromemail \n Message: \n $message";
        $headers = "From: $fromemail\n";
        $headers .= "Reply-To: $fromemail";

        if (mail ($toemail, $subject, $body, $headers))
            $alertmsg  = '<div class="alert alert-success text-center">Message sent successfully.  We will get back to you shortly!</div>';
        else
            $alertmsg = '<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">There is error in sending mail.  Please try again later.</div>';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: your question makes me think if bots can read PHP then what should to do to secure the database credentials :(

Comment: I don't understand your question. Your email is already hidden, php script is not visible (or should not be visible!) in page source. If you want some anti bot protection, use captcha or similar techniques....

Answer (score 0):

PHP is processed by the server, so it's not possible to read your email, so it's not necessary to do that.

All I can suggested is be carefully an filter your fields before to send to the PHP file, in php framework you have many functions to validate your fields but if you work directly with php you need to do that manually.

For example:

```
$email = htmlentities(substr($_POST["email"], 0, 100), ENT_QUOTES);
```

And as I can see your do this

```
filter_var($fromemail,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)
```

It's ok too. Finally I think it's more important to work with ReCaptcha to prevent spam.

Here you have a link:

https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/index.html